# Enlarging two objects at the same time in one animation action ising jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-manipulation

Please look at the following test page :
[sample page showing two images](http://www.sitestepper.com/en/enlarge-image-with-jquery.htm).

You see **small images which get a bit enlarged when you move over the image**.

I have used **jQuery** to do this, but ran into the following problem.

The only way I got the wanted effect was to enlarge the white `<div>` and making the image a percentage of the encapsulation `<div>`. If the `<div>` gets enlarged, the image automatically gets enlarged too.

Howerver, as you see on the sample page, the percentage a have choosen, enlarges to image so, that a 1 pixel out of alignment is visible (*the right border is 1 pixel larger than the other pixels*).

I could, of course, choose another percentage, but in stead want to ask the following question (being a programmer, I want to know how to solve similar problems, not this one in particular).

I would like to be able to **AND enlarge the `<div>` AND enlarge the `<IMG>`** during the **same hover action** - that way I could make sure that the enlarged image is the correct size.

I tried a couple of things, but never got the result - can anybody help me here ? Any help would be highly appreciated. I am learning to use jQuery and need to see some ways how to do things before I really can start using it.

The code of the page is below : (snippet from an existing page where I now want to include the enlarging effect - colours are just to see the different -areas).

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <title>enlarge image with jquery</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.sitestepper.com/versie2009/_js/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  html,body { margin:0; padding:0; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:normal; }
  *         { margin:0; padding:0; }

  img { border:none }

  .grid7x12jq {
     width:990px;
     height:260px;
     margin:10px 0 10px 10px;
     padding:9px 0px;
     clear:both;
     background-color:#ffddff;
  }
  .grid7x12jq .griditem {
     position:relative;
     width:137px;
     height:267px;
     float:left;
     border:none;
     padding:0px;
     margin-right:2px;
     margin-bottom:16px;
     background-color:#caffff;
  }
  .grid7x12jq .imgbox {
     position:absolute;
     left:0px;
     top:0px;
     border:none;
     width:137px;
     height:129px;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     clear:both;
  }
  .grid7x12jq .artbox {
     position:absolute;
     left:0px;
     top:138px;
     text-align:center;
     font-size:11px;
     border:none;
     padding:0px;
     width:137px;
     height:48px;
     line-height:14px;
     margin:0px;
  }

  .band-foto {
     position:absolute;
     left:10px;
     top:10px;
     width:118px;
     height:118px;
     background-color:white;
     border:1px solid black;
  }
  .band-foto img {
     width:88%;
     height:88%;
     padding:7px;
     /*position:absolute;*/
  }

  </style>

  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>jQuery Test - Enlarge images</h1>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.sitestepper.com/versie2009/_js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js'></script>

  <div class='grid7x12jq'>

     <div class='griditem'>
        <div class='imgbox'>
           <div class='band-foto'>
              <a href='http://www.adin.be/en/2ndpage.asp?dtn=07032-0181&amp;titel=Estate collier with brilliant and emeralds'><img
                 src='http://www.adinimages.com/low/07032-0181.P00.JPG' height='100%' width='100%' alt='Estate collier with brilliant and emeralds'/></a>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class='artbox'>
           <div style='height:30px;'>
              estate collier with bri...
           </div>
           3 photos ca.1970<br/>
             <a href='http://www.adin.be/en/2ndpage.asp?dtn=07032-0181&amp;titel=Estate collier with brilliant and emeralds'>view product</a><br/>
             online price:<br/>&euro; 99999<br/><br/>
             <form class='addbasketbutton' action='http://www.adin.be/en/action_-_sh_put_in_basket_(01).asp?BskDT=07032-0181' method='post'>
                <input type='submit' value='Add to basket'/>
             </form>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class='griditem'>
        <div class='imgbox'>
           <div class='band-foto'>
              <a href='http://www.adin.be/en/2ndpage.asp?dtn=07032-4420&amp;titel=Estate collier with brilliant and emeralds'><img
                 src='http://www.adinimages.com/low/07032-4420.P00.JPG' height='100%' width='100%' alt='Estate collier with brilliant and emeralds'/></a>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class='artbox'>
           <div style='height:30px;'>
              estate collier with bri...
           </div>
           3 photos ca.1970<br/>
             <a href='http://www.adin.be/en/2ndpage.asp?dtn=07032-4420&amp;titel=Estate collier with brilliant and emeralds'>view product</a><br/>
             online price:<br/>&euro; 99999<br/><br/>
             <form class='addbasketbutton' action='http://www.adin.be/en/action_-_sh_put_in_basket_(01).asp?BskDT=07032-4420' method='post'>
                <input type='submit' value='Add to basket'/>
             </form>
        </div>
     </div>

  </div>

  <div class='clear'></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(
   function()
   {
     $('.band-foto').hover(
       function()
       {
        $(this)
            .animate({ left:'5px', top:'5px', width:'130px', height:'130px'}, 'fast');
       } ,
       function(){
        $(this)
            .animate({ left:'10px', top:'10px', width:'118px', height:'118px'}, 'fast');
       }
     );
   }
  );
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Although I don't know how to do this *using jQuery* (but I don't know that library very well and in pure Javascript this is too cumbersome for me to write at this hour ;), the example suffers from three flaws: 1) when mousing out, the hover action isn't stopped, so your image will continue to zoom in; looks a bit counterintuitive; 2) the page that appears when I click on 'view product' has unused scrollbars; you should get rid of them, they are confusing; 3) € 99999 is *way* too much money for one jewel. :P

Comment: @ Marcel Korpel: Point 1) I noticed that too, but I didn't want to ask two question at the same time. I first want to see a solution to the question I ask, 2) To be honest, I don't know how to get rid of those scrollbars, the displayed text can be small or long and I don't know of a way to predict beforehand whether to just draw the text or use a edit box with scroll bars, 3) please browse around at that site - it has jewels way below the price tag shown :)

Comment: @Edelcom: About the scrollbars: what happens if you change the `overflow: scroll` to `overflow: auto` on `.dtntekst` (I don't have Firebug here, so I can't test)? http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html BTW, don't put a space between @ and my name, because I won't be notified if you do so.

Comment: @Edelcom: Just tested `overflow: auto` at home, it works as intended.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: Indeed it does. Amazing how you can overlook the most obvious things ... about the @... comment: I didn't even know it made a difference, didn't know that you would be notified. I just noticed other persons using this notation and found it logical. Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Comment: Yes, you will be (and always about comments on your own questions and answers, like these): the envelope at the top will turn yellow. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work/19757#19757 for a more concise explanation (and the rules about the @ sign).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't typically use animate, so I'll leave it to you to fill in the specifics, but jQuery lets you stuff as many functions in an event as you can handle--and even allows for chaining, meaning you can grab the selector and just keep going (so long as you are [still on or can get back to the right object](http://api.jquery.com/end/)). So that's what I'd do: go find the image and animate it, too.

(Numbers are just guesses. And I changed formatting to save space.)

```
function(){
 $('.band-foto').hover(
   function(){
    $(this)
      .animate({ left:'5px', top:'5px', width:'130px', height:'130px'}, 'fast')
      .find("img").animate({ width:'120px', height:'120px'}, 'fast');
   } ,
   function(){
    $(this)
      .animate({ left:'10px', top:'10px', width:'118px', height:'118px'}, 'fast')
      .find("img").animate({ width:'100px', height:'100px'}, 'fast');
   });
});
```

Now, there might be a lag, I'm not sure. If so, you could try unchaining it and just making it into two (`$(this).animate()` and `$(this).find()`), but this might suffer from the same fate. My gut says you want to refigure your CSS so that the DIV is only as big as the image plus padding, and so animating the image is all you need to do.

Comment: +1 I agree. Good answer - will try them. Regarding the using another approach in CSS, you're correct, but still I want to know how to animate two objects at the same time - just to get the hang of jQuery. I know about chaining, but thought that this will do the animation in sequence. I will let you know the results.

Comment: Oh, if you thought the ', function()' was allowing another function, it's not. Under .hover(), the first function() area is for 'stuff to do on mouseenter' and the second is for 'stuff to do on mouseleave'. Sorry if I'm telling you something else you know, just want to be explicit.

Comment: Actually, I do assume you know that, since you had the animation working to begin with. Ah well. Good luck, and let me know how it goes.